# Access a remote Laravel 5 web app using ajax through a Hybrid App

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, csrf, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a Hybrid App where I use ajax requests to connect to a remote database. The database is accessed through the **Laravel(5) framework**. When I send requests to the remote laravel web app, I get the following case.

`Error with message, No Access Control Allow Origin Header Present.`

To solve this problem I added the access control headers to the `index.php` at `public/` directory. Then the above error no longer occurs(Yes, I know that we can do the same using a Middleware and it is the recommended way). But then an internal server error occurs saying `csrf Token mismatch exception`. I know that if this was a web appilication, we could have easily added the csrf_token. Since this is a hybrid app, I cant set a token since I can't run any PHP here and I can't obtain a token by an ajax request.

Up to now, I have read almost every thread related to this in Laravel Forums. But there were no feasible answer. Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why cant you disable csrf token verification from laravel.??  Since you are not posting a form to it.

Comment: Yes, i just figured it out myself. Thanks a lot for your consideration. :-)